# Compare 2 dataframes with unequal no. of rows for finding unique records in 1 dataframe using PYTHON

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Need to construct two dataframes containing SQL query outputs from 2 different environments:
DF1 : Coming from Env1
DF1 --> {11,13,15,17,20}
DF2 : Coming from Env2
DF2 --> {11,12,13,15,16,17,20,25}

Now I need to extract the values (12,16,25) from DF2, so that I can remove it from DF2 and make DF1 and DF2 equal in size in order to apply 'Compare' function.

Am trying to use Merge but am getting same no. of records if I use left or right join.

Is there a better way to get this done ?

df_all = df1.merge(df2.drop_duplicates(), on=['PK'], how='left')

am getting same records as df2 in df_all if I do left or right join

Comment: Have you tried an inner join?

Comment: is df1 always a subset of df2?

Comment: Yes I have tried Inner join but it is not helping. Also df1 is smaller than df2.

Answer (score 0):

if I'm following you well then this is what you wanna do.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'PK': [11, 13, 15, 17, 20]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'PK': [11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 20, 25]})
to_remove = set(df2['PK']) - set(df1['PK'])
df_remove = pd.DataFrame({'PK': list(to_remove)})

# Merge df_remove with df2 using an inner join
df2_new = df2.merge(df_remove, on='PK', how='inner')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 
I did try but am getting error to get the df to_remove. Can we please connect on same.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to achieve is the following:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'PK': [11, 13, 15, 17, 20]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'PK': [11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 20, 25]})
df = df2[df2['PK'].isin(df1['PK'])]

# if you want the opposite then you can do the following:
df = df2[~df2['PK'].isin(df1['PK'])]
```

Comment: would be nice to accept the answer if it works for you :)

Comment: The 'isin' functions is solving my purpose. thanks

Comment: You could flag the answer as accepted then

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for something like this

```
import pandas as pd
# creating the dataframes:

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ENV1': [11,13,15,17,20]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ENV2': [11,12,13,15,16,17,20,25]})



df3 = (df1.merge(df2, right_on='ENV2', left_on='ENV1', how='right', indicator=True)
     .query('_merge == "right_only"')
     .drop('_merge', 1))

df3
```

and then drop (12,16,25) from df2:

```
df2 = df2.drop(df3.index, axis=0) # Step 2
df2
```